# Set table cell color from database

Tags: asp.net, html, code-behind

I'm overthinking this. I have colors stored in a database table, and I want to set the background of specific cells in a table to those colors. In other words:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td ???set color here???>
            ...content...
        </td>
        <td ???next color here???>
            ...next content...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Originally I had Panels surrounding each piece of content and I set their background color in the code-behind, which worked fine until I had varying size panels, which threw off the layout. What's the easiest way to feed the color values from the database to the `<td>` element? Note that the colors are user-configurable, so I can't have them pre-defined in a CSS file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a custom CSS file with database data by creating a custom HttpHandler.
But the simple way woud be:

```
<td style="background-color:#000000">
...
</td>
```

with

```
<td style='background-color:<%= GetCellColor() %>'>
...
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the DB populate the CSS?

```
.dark {
   background-color:[database field]
}

<td class='dark'></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a table with fixed number of rows/columns?

You might use ASP style of code here.
td backcolor="<%= MyColorProvider.FirstCellColor %>" .....

Where MyColorProvider.FirstCellColor is the string representation of color (it could be a hex string as well).

Comment: this is an old html sintax, it's better to use style="background-color:#000000", or a css stylesheet. And the correct old sintax is td bgcolor="#000000"

Answer (score 0):

You could output a css file fromt the database when the application starts up, and then include the css file in the master page.